# Is there any way to invert/flip the result figure?

Tags: ios, swift, plot, 3d, scenekit

Using iOS - Swift Xcode 14
I have drawn an image using some points... and I got an image as output. But the image is an inverted or a flipped image.
I used several code for flipping/Inverting the image but none of the code was working.
by using of some codes the result image going out of the screen.
The code provided here is 90% correct code but the image is flipped/inverted.

```
import SceneKit

class StairTwoDSceneViewController: UIViewController {

    var plotPointsArray: [[Double]] = [[0.0,0.0,0.0], [0.229,0.0,0.005], [0.229,-0.0249,0.1926], [0.4566,-0.0249,0.2073], [0.4341,-0.0315,0.3989],[0.6754,-0.0315,0.4039],[0.6513,-0.0315,0.5892], [0.8782,-0.0315,0.5971], [0.8541,-0.0315,0.7834],[1.0765,-0.0315,0.78781]]
    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 0.1 // Adjust this value to increase or decrease line thickness
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.02 // Adjust this value to control the size of the corner circles

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let sceneView = SCNView(frame: view.bounds)
        sceneView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        view.addSubview(sceneView)

        let scene = SCNScene()

        if plotPointsArray.count > 0 {
            let pointsNode = SCNNode()

            for (index, point) in plotPointsArray.enumerated() {
                guard point.count == 2 || point.count == 3 else {
                    continue // Skip invalid points
                }

                // Adjust the y-coordinate to place the green sphere at the left bottom
                let spherePosition = SCNVector3(
                    x: Float(point[0]),
                    y: Float(point.count == 2 ? -0.0315 : -point[1]), // Flip and adjust y-coordinate
                    z: Float(point[point.count - 1])
                )
                let sphereNode = drawSphere(at: spherePosition, radius: cornerRadius, color: index == 0 ? UIColor.green : UIColor.red)
                pointsNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
            }

            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(pointsNode)

            for i in 0..<plotPointsArray.count - 1 {
                let currentPoint = plotPointsArray[i]
                let nextPoint = plotPointsArray[i + 1]

                guard currentPoint.count == nextPoint.count else {
                    continue // Skip invalid points
                }

                let start = SCNVector3(currentPoint[0], currentPoint.count == 2 ? -0.0315 : -currentPoint[1], currentPoint[currentPoint.count - 1])
                let end = SCNVector3(nextPoint[0], nextPoint.count == 2 ? -0.0315 : -nextPoint[1], nextPoint[nextPoint.count - 1])

                let lineGeometry = SCNGeometry.lineGeometry(from: start, to: end)
                let lineNode = SCNNode(geometry: lineGeometry)
                scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lineNode)
            }
        }

        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.eulerAngles.x = -Float.pi / 2
        cameraNode.eulerAngles.y = 0
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(0.5, 2.5, 0.5)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        sceneView.scene = scene
        sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
    }



    func drawLine(from start: SCNVector3, to end: SCNVector3, thickness: CGFloat, color: UIColor) -> SCNNode {
        let lineGeometry = SCNGeometry.lineGeometry(from: start, to: end)
        lineGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = color

        let lineNode = SCNNode(geometry: lineGeometry)
        lineNode.position = SCNVector3((start.x + end.x) / 2, (start.y + end.y) / 2, (start.z + end.z) / 2)
        lineNode.eulerAngles.z = -atan2(end.x - start.x, end.y - start.y)

        return lineNode
    }

    func drawSphere(at position: SCNVector3, radius: CGFloat, color: UIColor) -> SCNNode {
        let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: radius)
        let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry)
        sphereNode.position = position
        sphereNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = color
        return sphereNode
    }
}

extension SCNGeometry {
    static func lineGeometry(from start: SCNVector3, to end: SCNVector3) -> SCNGeometry {
        let indices: [Int32] = [0, 1]

        let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: [start, end])
        let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .line)

        return SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])
    }
}
extension UIImage {
    func rotate(degrees: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return nil
        }
        context.rotate(by: degrees * CGFloat.pi / 180)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: self.size))
        let rotatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return rotatedImage
    }
}
```

[image: Output Image Based on given code]

Actually I want the Inverted-image like this below
[image: The Output i need]

Note : Dont change the points, the points getting from backend. I have used sample points here

I need to flip/Invert the image.

Comment: If you have the whole construction in organized one "master-node", you could probably then just change the scale of that master-node like: masterNode.scale = SCNVector3(1.0, -1.0, 1.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the "stair steps" you have generated, the camera is looking *from the **Y-axis*** ... the "stairs" are descending on the ***Z-axis***.

Depending on what you want to do, you can either flip the camera:

```
    cameraNode.eulerAngles.x = -Float.pi / 2
    //cameraNode.eulerAngles.y = 0
    cameraNode.eulerAngles.y = -Float.pi / 2
```

Or, translate the Z coordinates to invert the stairs:

```
    if plotPointsArray.count > 0 {
        let pointsNode = SCNNode()

        // only use elements that have x,y,z values
        plotPointsArray.removeAll(where: {$0.count != 3})

        // will never fail (because we're only here if .count > 0)
        //  but safely unwrap anyway
        guard let lastPoint = plotPointsArray.last
        else { return }
        
        // assuming for now the z-values are from 0.0 to a positive value
        let maxZ = lastPoint[2]
        
        for (index, point) in plotPointsArray.enumerated() {
            
            // Adjust the Z-coordinate to place the green sphere at the left bottom
            let spherePosition = SCNVector3(
                x: Float(point[0]),
                y: Float(point[1]),
                z: Float(maxZ - point[2])
            )

            let sphereNode = drawSphere(at: spherePosition, radius: cornerRadius, color: index == 0 ? UIColor.green : UIColor.red)
            pointsNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
        }
        
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(pointsNode)
        
        // let's use those sphere nodes to generate the
        //  "connecting lines" instead of re-converting the plotPointsArray
        var startVect: SCNVector3 = pointsNode.childNodes[0].position
        
        for (i, n) in pointsNode.childNodes.enumerated() {
            
            // skip the first time through
            //  since we have only the starting point
            guard i != 0 else {
                continue
            }
            
            let nextVect = n.position
            
            let lineGeometry = SCNGeometry.lineGeometry(from: startVect, to: nextVect)
            let lineNode = SCNNode(geometry: lineGeometry)
            
            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lineNode)
            
            startVect = nextVect
        }

    }
```

---

Alternatively, if we add the "spheres" **and** the "connector lines" to `pointsNode`, we could "invert" the entire node by scaling it and then moving it down (so the last sphere will be at Zero on the Z-axis):

```
        if plotPointsArray.count > 0 {
            let pointsNode = SCNNode()
            
            // only use elements that have x,y,z values
            plotPointsArray.removeAll(where: {$0.count != 3})
            
            // will never fail (because we're only here if .count > 0)
            //  but safely unwrap anyway
            guard let lastPoint = plotPointsArray.last
            else { return }
            
            // assuming for now the z-values are from 0.0 to a positive value
            let maxZ = lastPoint[2]
            
            var startVect: SCNVector3!
            
            for (index, point) in plotPointsArray.enumerated() {
                
                // Adjust the Z-coordinate to place the green sphere at the left bottom
                let spherePosition = SCNVector3(
                    x: Float(point[0]),
                    y: Float(point[1]),
                    z: Float(point[2])
                )
                
                let sphereNode = drawSphere(at: spherePosition, radius: cornerRadius, color: index == 0 ? UIColor.green : UIColor.red)
                pointsNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
                
                // add the "sphere connector lines" so they are
                //  part of the points node and will rotate/move along with it
                let nextVect = spherePosition
                if let sv = startVect {
                    let lineGeometry = SCNGeometry.lineGeometry(from: startVect, to: nextVect)
                    let lineNode = SCNNode(geometry: lineGeometry)
                    pointsNode.addChildNode(lineNode)
                }
                startVect = nextVect
                
            }
            
            let (minVec, maxVec) = pointsNode.boundingBox
            
            // scale on the z-axis
            //  and move by the height of pointsNode minus the sphere radius
            //  so the LAST point (the center of the LAST sphere) will be at z: 0.0
            var m = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(1.0, 1.0, -1.0)
            m = SCNMatrix4Translate(m, 0.0, 0.0, maxVec.z - Float(cornerRadius))
            pointsNode.pivot = m
            
            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(pointsNode)
            
        }
```

with either approach, this is the result (I added axis lines for clarity - x-axis: red, y-axis: green, z-axis: blue):

[image]